# What are good resources to self-teach mathematics?

Tags: education, learning, online-resources

I am teaching myself mathematics using textbooks and I'm currently studying the UK a-level syllabus (I think in the USA this is equivalent to pre-college algebra & calculus). Two resources I have found invaluable for this are this website (http://math.stackexchange.com) and Wolfram Alpha (http://wolframalpha.com). I am very grateful that with those tools, I have managed to understand any questions/doubts I have had so far.

Can anyone recommended other valuable resources for the self-taught student of mathematics at this basic level?

I hope questions of this format are valid here?

Thanks!

Comment: 2K views and only one answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this site as well as wolfram|alpha are both excellent resources for teaching yourself math!

In addition, I would suggest looking at [this site](http://patrickjmt.com/). It provides tons of great math videos, if you are like me and too lazy to read your book sometimes. :) [KhanAcademy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) is also good, but I do prefer the latter. If you can afford it, perhaps you should consider getting into an online class? That way you get more resources and a professor to directly speak to. Not to mention, most math jobs require that you show some accreditation (e.g. a degree). Not exactly sure about your situation, but thought I would mention it. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @Mr_CryptoPrime, http://patrickjmt.com looks excellent. I study computer science at university but have always only just "got by" with any mathematical understanding. So I am re-studying maths up to pre-university level. Actually I quite enjoy it now and I hope to continue into more advanced topics, so online classes may be a great idea. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, I am in my second semester of college, double majoring in applied mathematics and computer science. Ironically, I am failing my algorithms and discrete math class. :( I think I just over did it. Just a couple grand (at minimum wage) and 5 months of my life, oh well...lol I have taken college algebra, pre-calc, calc I online (and plan doing calc. II this summer). They have worked out fairly well I suppose. Much easier than driving all the way up to the University (an hour away). Nice to meet you!

Comment: Nice to meet you too, good luck with the course!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but this is for anyone else who might want this in the future.

For direct information about the a-level search TLmaths on YouTube, who has a playlist of just under 1000 videos covering the entire course.

For lots of free practice questions visit physics and maths tutor.

I have recently found openstax for many great maths books, but is not specific to the a-level.

Professor Leonard on YouTube is great for any level of maths, and has great lectures.

I hope people find something here to help them learn.